# should adding a UILabel in a custom UIView be in drawRect or initWithFrame / custom setup method

Tags: ios

I'm not a full-time iOS dev and have to make some changes to someone else's code. We have a custom view where a `UILabel` is added in *drawRect* like this (edited for brevity):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  UILabel *myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
  myLabel.text=@"here is some text";
  [self addSubview:myLabel];

}
```

I have never really seen this and thought that drawRect was ONLY for adding drawing operations (and have only seen `UIBezierPaths`). Should this be moved to ***initWithFrame*** (or a common setup method like setupMyView). Or is ok to leave in drawRect? Is there anything besides custom drawing that should be in drawRect?

Sorry for asking a somewhat basic question but even reading the Apple docs leave a bit to be desired.

Comment: Putting it in a common setup method would be much preferred. drawRect can be called many times, and it's best to not use it unless you're doing custom drawing.

Comment: thx (again) @rdelmar ; it seemed really wonky when I saw it. Is it fair to say that only true drawing. Would animations (like a [UIView animateWithDuration) be in drawRect? thx

Comment: No, animateWithDuration should no be in draw rect either.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a very good reason to setup the view's subviews from within the drawRect method (I can think of none) I would strongly suggest leaving drawRect as purely a drawing method and move that addSubview stuff out of there! I would suggest overriding the -init method that is currently used to initiate the parent view.  For example:

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame]) {
        UILabel *myLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
        myLabel.text=@"here is some text";
        [self addSubview:myLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not do anything like that in drawRect. One method I've used in the past is to add it to layoutSubviews, because at that point the view is aware of the true bounds/frame. You'll want to ensure that you only generate the view stuff once, as layoutSubviews is called many times, such as on rotation. I usually do something like the following, where `_viewGenerated` is an instance variable:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!_viewGenerated) {
        [self generateView];
        _viewGenerated = YES;
    }
}

- (void)generateView {
    // do everything with any labels, images, etc., here...
}
```